# How much drinking water can I get back

Tags: experimental-chemistry

If I was to boil a gallon of sea water and collect the condensation, how much drinking water would I get back?

Comment: It's sort of a loaded question (actually, not clear enough) since it doesn't specify temperature or location.

Comment: @TryHard I guess the "location" is sea level, and that pretty much also defines the temperature, about 100°C. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to interpret this as a question asking for the maximum theoretical water recoverable, and not a reasonable expectation for a distillation apparatus (which would vary from apparatus from to apparatus).

According to Encyclopedia Britannica, seawater is 96.5% water by mass. In addition, the density of seawater is around 1.030g/mL.

There are around 3785mL in a gallon, so the mass of a gallon of seawater is 3898g. Multiply that by 0.965, and the mass of water in it is 3762g. Since the density of water is 1.00, you could expect to recover 3.762L of water with a perfect distillation apparatus and 100% recovery.